# Regex and python match

Tags: python, regex

Hello all and sorry to bother with another regex question...
This time the problem I have is that I'm unable to match or exclude some strings out of a regexp:

Strings to compare against:

```
EVENT DATA
EVENT
EVENT SEC-1193 10222
EVENT META
```

I want this regex to match only `EVENT SEC-1193 10222` and it's like this:

```
EVENT\s[\w'-]*\s[\w'-]*
```

The problem is that it matches everything... Any help in the reghell would be highly appreciated

Comment: can you be more specific about your matching criteria? Why don't you just match the string exactly, if that's all you need to do?

Comment: * means zero or more ...this reminds me of that regex quote... now you have 2 problems ...

Comment: Second Zoran's comment above...the * operand returns all the string with 0 or more occurrences of EVENT\s[\w'-]*\s[\w'-]. That's why it matches everything

Comment: My brain short-circuits when dealing with regexp stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EVENT\s[\w'-]+\s[0-9]+
```

Seems to be a bit better. Try testing your regex's with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ or http://regex101.com/

Comment: Indeed looks better :D

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/hackl/www/lab/turkshop/slides/regex-cheatsheet.pdf

An outstanding reference.

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` instead of `*`:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r"EVENT\s[\w'-]+\s[\w'-]+")
>>> r.search("EVENT DATA")
>>> r.search("EVENT")
>>> r.search("EVENT SEC-1193 10222")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x8e04100>
>>> r.search("EVENT META")
```